# Why can't I use a function to simplify my "for loops"

Tags: php, function

I build a  webpage to crack simple MD5 hash of a four digit pin for fun. The method I used was basically try all combination and check against the MD5 value the user has entered. Below is the PHP code I created to accomplish the goal.

Debug Output:

```php
<?php
$answer = "PIN not found";
if (isset($_GET['md5'])) {
  $txt = 'abcdefjhig';
  $time_pre = microtime(TRUE);
  $value = $_GET['md5'];
  $show = 15;

  for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $first = $i;
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++) {
      $second = $j;
      for ($k = 0; $k <= 9; $k++) {
        $third = $k;
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 9; $x++) {
          $fourth = $x;
          $whole = $first . $second . $third . $fourth;
          $check = hash('md5', $whole);
          if ($check == $value) {
            $answer = $whole;
            echo "The pin is $answer";
          }
          if ($show > 0) {
            print"$check $whole \n";
            $show = $show - 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
  $time_post = microtime(TRUE);
  print "Elapsed time:";
  print $time_post - $time_pre;
}
?>
```

Notice that in the middle there are four very similar for loops,I tried to simplify this by using functions, but it just returns one four digit number which is 9999 instead of all of them.
Below is the function I created:

```php
function construct($input){
  for($i=0; $i<=9, $i++){
    $input=$i;
  } 
  return $input
}
```

Then I tried to call this function for four times to form all of the four digit numbers but it just gives me 9999. Can anybody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For something like this, wouldn't it just be easier to have 1 for loop which goes from 0 - 9999? (you would have to ensure the number is padded to 4 digits with 0's)

Comment: Your for loops in the main script body are nested within each other, while the function "construction" is not. They are fundamentally performing different tasks in the way you are presenting them. Also - your construction function will only ever return 9 because $input = $i, and 9 is the final number that $i becomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=9999 ; $i++) { 
   $whole = sprintf('%04d', $i);
    $check=hash('md5', $whole);
    if($check==$value){
        $answer=$whole;
        echo "The pin is $answer";
        break; //remove this if you do not want to break the loop here
    }
    if ($show>0) {
        print"$check $whole \n";
        $show=$show-1;          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using numbers from 0 to 9999, so why just loop through those numbers? You can add zero's by using `str_pad()` like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
    $whole = str_pad($i, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Also I'd like to mention that you really should think about better formatting of your code, especially indentation

Comment: Thank you for help me. I am new to programming, sorry about the indentation.